# How can you set Adobe Reader's save settings to the last directory a file was saved in?

Tags: adobe-reader

Is there a way to change the save settings of Adobe Reader so that it opens the directory that the last file was saved in?

For example, I go to open a file from email in Adobe Reader and "Save As" in a different location with a different name.  To repeat this process, saving the file again opens the default save directory, instead of the last used directory.

Any thoughts?

Comment: My understanding is you open Adobe Reader from your email client, save the PDF to another location, then close Adobe Reader. Then you open another PDF, go to save it and instead of going to the last place you saved to, it's going to the default place instead? If so, unfortunately, I don't think Adobe Reader has a way to configure the default save location.

Answer (score 1):

I created a Macro Express script, activated by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, that opens the "Save As" dialog (by sending <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>),  and then this:

1. Sends the desired path, e.g., c:\XXX\YYY\ZZZ\
2. Presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Navigates to the list of files and folders by sending <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice.
4. Puts focus on the first item on the list by sending Down arrow.

The script does not remember the last path entered, but if you choose a path wisely as your default, the script will at least take you close to where you usually want to be saving files.

```
Lock Keyboard and Mouse
Text Type (Simulate Keystrokes): <CONTROL><SHIFT>s
Delay: 300 milliseconds
Text Type (Simulate Keystrokes): \\Vault1\home1$\alan\My Documents
Text Type (Simulate Keystrokes): <ENTER>
Delay: 100 milliseconds
Text Type (Simulate Keystrokes): <SHIFT><TAB><SHIFT><TAB>
Delay: 100 milliseconds
Text Type (Simulate Keystrokes): <ARROW DOWN>
Unlock Keyboard and Mouse
```